# Envelope Theorem and Factor Mix Intuition

Tags: utility, production-function, optimization, lagrangian

**Brief Summary of question:**

I'm frustrated with the intuition of the envelope theorem that when input costs change, our envelope theorem tells us we do not need to re-optimise demand levels.

**Context:**

I understand that the envelope theorem is telling us that when we have our maximum/minimum value function e.g. a indirect utility function $V(p_x, p_y, m)$ or a cost function $C(w,r, q)$ that if we want to know how a change in one of these parameters affects our optimal value e.g. $\frac{\partial V}{\partial p_x}$, we can just differentiate the underlying Lagrangian or even just the objective function, evaluated at the optimal input value $(x\star, y\star)$ and this will give us the required value.

The underlying idea being that we don't need to worry about the behind the scenes mechanics of re-optimising our levels of demand, and instead we can just worry about the direct affect, namely $∆P_x x^\star$ .

Specifically in the [explanation](https://youtu.be/QzcCa2BvPXE?t=178) below the author used the phrase. Note: he is referring to a fall in rent i.e. $r_2 < r_1$ leading us to optimise away from labour and towards using capital instead.

> "What's more if changing our factor mix could have reduced labour costs without being fully offset by increase in capital costs, **then we had too much labour in the first place.**"
> [I assume we could write this increase in total capital costs as  $r_2(k_1+∆k)]$

But this bothers me because in all reality, if a factor input cost increases, then of course it's going to affect our input mix? The proof being if we simply re-did the optimisation process again, using this new $r_2$ we would get a $(x\star, y\star)'$ different to $(x\star, y\star)$. As is the whole meaning behind the use of the word envelope, our cost function is a (lower) envelope of all the possible optimal costs given specific parameter values.

So the statement just seems a bit pointless to me? Because unless changes are so small, we surely would have to adjust our input mix in a meaningful way? Maybe my frustration is invalid, as on a meta level I guess I'm just critiquing the use of calculus in economics?
I assume empirical studies have shown that thinking about it in this way with these tiny changes is useful/accurate.